# If $a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta=m$, $b\sin^2\psi+a\cos^2\psi=n$, $a\tan\theta=b\tan\psi$, then $\frac1m+\frac1n=\frac1a+\frac1b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> If
> $$\begin{align}
> a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta &=m \tag1\\[4pt]
> b\sin^2\psi+a\cos^2\psi &=n \tag2\\[4pt]
> a\tan\theta&=b\tan\psi \tag3
> \end{align}$$
> prove that $$\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$

Unfortunately, I can't isolate $a$ or $b$ here so I decided to calculate $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}$

I got the result as $$\frac{a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta+b\sin^2\psi+a\cos^2\psi}{(a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta)(b\sin^2\psi+a\cos^2\psi)}=$$ $$\frac{a(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\psi)+b(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\psi)}{(a\sin^2\theta+b\cos^2\theta)(b\sin^2\psi+a\cos^2\psi)}$$ I can't proceed further. Enlighten me on this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (3) implies $a\sin\theta\cos\psi=b\sin\psi\cos\theta$ which shows up in the denominator. you can also write $a=b\frac{\tan\psi}{\tan\theta}$

Comment: The previous answer I just indicated could be written in terms of cross ratios...